# Subnet mask for maximum number of hosts?

Tags: networking, subnet

How would I configure a subnet mask for a maximum number of hosts on a network segment?  For example, let's say I need a maximum of 6 hosts per network segment for a Class C address.

Comment: [learn how it works](http://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work), or [look it up on a table/calculator](http://www.subnet-calculator.com/)

Comment: Oh, and if your teacher or some reference is talking about 'Class C' addresses, then find a replacement.  Classful addressing was deprecated over a decade ago.  We use CIDR now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is confusing.  Are you asking how you can further segment a class C address to have subnets with 6 hosts?  If so, you can use a mask of 255.255.255.240 for 16 subnets with 14 *available* addresses because the first and last addresses are reserved for network and broadcast respectively.

Comment: Hi SaxDaddy... sorry for the confusion, I am still a newbie and grappling with subnetting.  Yes, I am asking how I can further segment a class C address to have subnets with 6 hosts.  Can you please explain how you came up with the mask of 255.255.255.248?  I understand about the first 3 octets, just need to know how you came up with 248 for the 4th octet?

Comment: No worries. Subnets masks are like a filter that block some numbers (like the first 3 in a class C) for identifying the network and pass others for the host identifier. So since the last octet of your class C has 8 bits, 248 becomes `1111 1000` where the ones are part of the network and the zeros are host addresses. The first 5 ones become hex FA or 248 allowing 7 possible IP addresses.  But remember that 0 and 255 are reserved so this actually allows 5 max hosts per subnet (my bad).  Hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect!  This explanation is really helpful, thanks for your response!

Comment: NP.  BTW, I edited my response to correct myself since my original answer would have given you 5 max hosts per subnet.